# Where can I find the form, schedule and line where the interest/dividends/royalties etc from foreign accounts are reported, when those values are 0?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dividends, foreign-income, turbotax

I am a US resident. I have a non-US bank accounts. Therefore, I fill form 8938 on Turbotax.

In form 8938, I need to indicate the "schedule and line" and the "form and line" where the interest, dividends, royalties and other income from foreign accounts are reported (ignore the value in the "schedule and line" and the "form and line" columns in the screenshot):

[image]

In one of the accounts, I did receive dividends, which are reported on Form 1040, Schedule B, Line 5. However, I received no interest, royalties or other income. In other accounts, I received nothing (no dividends, interest, royalties or other income). They don't show up on Form 1040, Schedule B (there's no reports such as "Bank name: 0").

How can I find the "schedule and line" and the "form and line" where the interest, dividends, royalties and other income from foreign accounts are reported, when those values are 0? Am I supposed to create Form 1099-DIV, Form 1099-INT and Form 1099-MISC with zeroes in it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... If you received no dividends or interest then what it is you're trying to report?

Comment: @littleadv in the screenshot from the question,  TurboTax asks me to indicate the "schedule and line" and the "form and line" where the interest, dividends, royalties and other income from foreign accounts are reported. I also don't see the point in it. Shall I just put 0 or NA in it? (If I leave the field empty, TurboTax keeps complaining)

Comment: @littleadv TurboTax asks me to enter something in these fields when TurboTax does its final checks. In one of the accounts, I did receive dividends, which are reported on Form 1040, Schedule B, Line 5. However, I received no interest, royalties or other income. In other accounts, I received nothing (no dividends, interest, royalties or other income). They don't show up on Form 1040, Schedule B (there's no reports such as "Bank name: 0").
Am I supposed to create Form 1099-DIV, Form 1099-INT and Form 1099-MISC with zeroes in it? Or simply enter 0 or NA in these fields?

Comment: Edited your question so that it is asking what you actually are asking.

Comment: @littleadv If I leave these fields empty, TurboTax complains each time it check my taxes.

Comment: Ask what you want to ask and spare your life story, seriously.

Comment: @littleadv I didn't know that the fields were not relevant to my situation.  I believed I could create Form 1099-DIV, Form 1099-INT and Form 1099-MISC with zeroes in them, and refer to it on Form 8938.

Comment: (Rolled back due to the reason mentionned in my last comment. Note that I'm not the only one with that same question, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/tax/comments/12a880x/how_can_i_find_the_schedule_and_line_and_the_form/jf0b2xg/ I expect many US tax residents who immigrated to the United States have the same issue.)

Answer (score 1):

You updated in the comment that what you're actually asking is what to fill in a field that Turbo Tax doesn't allow leaving empty, but is not relevant to you.

`"N/A"` is the common way in the American bureaucratic system to denote "not applicable" and is what is usually put in such cases. If the field is numeric and demands a numeric value, then the numeric value denoting non-existence is `"0"`.

Comment: Thanks, technically I believe I could create Form 1099-DIV, Form 1099-INT and Form 1099-MISC with zeroes in them, and refer to it on Form 8938. That'd be very stupid but I'm just trying to follow what the IRS likes.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt None of these are part of your tax return, in your specific situation the question is what line item on what form *of your tax return* the income shows up at.

Comment: Good point. I guess I'll go with N/A then. That makes sense. Strange that TurboTax doesn't do it itself. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes TT will ask you to explicitly enter a value to make sure you haven't forgotten to check something, especially if your other answers suggest that there might be a nonzero value. That's one of the advantages of using tax software. But it does mean you will sometimes have to explicitly say zero rather than leaving a field blank. Asking for help on that field may or may not be useful as a sanity check.